# Does Jboss 7.1 AS supports ejb 2.1?

Tags: jboss, migration, ejb, jboss7.x, ejb-2.x

it seems jboss AS 7.1 supports ejb 2.1.Our ejb 2.1 based application is deployed on jboss 5 AS. We are migrating it to jboss7.1.  but i want to know what are the additional configurations required to run ejb 2.1 without any errors?

Answer (score 0):

EJB2 is still supported in AS7.x, the issue might be that AS7 is a new implementation and some of the tuning options and configuations are not available for AS7 - especially the EntityBean CMP.
There are some added for EAP6 (based on AS7) you might download the unsupported version.

Wildfly (the successor of JBossAS) will not continue to support EJB2 EntityBeans because EJB3.2 declare it as optional.
Note EJB2 session beans are still supported but I recommend to upgrade it to EJB3 this should faily simple.
You might keep the EJB2 interfaces to provide an interface for EJB2 clients, but I expect effort for the client as well as the lookup Strings changed.

If the appliation should be kept for the future I would recommend to migrate to EJB3